# Form input feedback has wrong position when it has a button addon in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've added both feedback and a button addon to an input field in my form. My HTML is the following:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="authorization_id">AutorisationsID</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input name="authorization_id" class="form-control" type="text">
            <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <a href="#" id="authid-info-btn" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-info" role="button" data-position="auto right" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="click" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign">
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 control-label control-label-left-align"></div>
</div>
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

And here's what I want it to look like

[image]

The feedback is positioned wrong when the button addon is present. Am I missing something or does Bootstrap not support this design?

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you want it to look like... you want the question mark icon on the left? like I have in my form on nu-creative.com/contact.php?

Comment: @FeiLauren I've included an image of how I wan't it to look like

Comment: Are you comfortable using CSS? I would need a live example to tell you exactly what you need

Comment: Not clear where `x` comes from  http://plnkr.co/edit/B81ENVPGuu8j5MXlnI3g?p=preview

Comment: [From the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation): "Icons, labels, and input groups: Manual positioning of feedback icons is required [...] for input groups with an add-on on the right. [...] For input groups, adjust the `right` value to an appropriate pixel value depending on the width of your addon." Example: http://jsbin.com/conudi/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2):

I slapped your content into a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2459/

But I don't know how to get the X to come up. Is there any way you can emulate that in the fiddle?

It will be something like

```
.redX {
position: relative;
left: -10px;
}
```

Or possibly a small adjustment to margin or padding. It could be a lot of things but likely a simple-ish fix in css. A live example would be best, really.